# Spring Boot: I have a kafka broker code that makes the application get stuck

Tags: spring, spring-boot, apache-kafka

Spring Boot: I have a kafka broker code that is in the application which listens to a topic. I have a controller which has api endpoints. My kafka polls to the topic. When i start the application i see kafka getting started but the problem is my endpoints are not working. Even the application is not up on the port mentioned. I need to test my endpoints but i cannot. I see my kafka getting started and working fine, but i dont see the prompt saying that the application started at port XXXX and the endpoints are not working.

Logs on console:

> 2018-04-17 17:18:59.447  INFO 59720 --- [           main]
>   c.f.s.e.EventAggregationApplication      : Starting
>   EventAggregationApplication on FPTECHS48s-MacBook-Pro.local with PID
>   59720 (/Users/fptechs48/IdeaProjects/event-aggregation/target/classes
>   started by fptechs48 in
>   /Users/fptechs48/IdeaProjects/event-aggregation) 2018-04-17
>   17:18:59.450 DEBUG 59720 --- [           main]
>   c.f.s.e.EventAggregationApplication      : Running with Spring Boot
>   v1.5.9.RELEASE, Spring v4.3.13.RELEASE 2018-04-17 17:18:59.450  INFO
>   59720 --- [           main] c.f.s.e.EventAggregationApplication      :
>   The following profiles are active: dev 2018-04-17 17:18:59.487  INFO
>   59720 --- [           main] s.c.a.AnnotationConfigApplicationContext :
>   Refreshing
>   org.springframework.context.annotation.AnnotationConfigApplicationContext@1198b989:
>   startup date [Tue Apr 17 17:18:59 IST 2018]; root of context hierarchy
>   2018-04-17 17:18:59.894  INFO 59720 --- [           main]
>   trationDelegate$BeanPostProcessorChecker : Bean
>   'org.springframework.kafka.annotation.KafkaBootstrapConfiguration' of
>   type
>   [org.springframework.kafka.annotation.KafkaBootstrapConfiguration$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$b36fb556]
>   is not eligible for getting processed by all BeanPostProcessors (for
>   example: not eligible for auto-proxying) 2018-04-17 17:19:00.521  INFO
>   59720 --- [           main] o.a.k.clients.admin.AdminClientConfig    :
>   AdminClientConfig values:     bootstrap.servers = [13.126.200.243:9092]
>     client.id =     connections.max.idle.ms = 300000    metadata.max.age.ms =
>   300000    metric.reporters = []   metrics.num.samples = 2
>     metrics.recording.level = INFO  metrics.sample.window.ms = 30000
>     receive.buffer.bytes = 65536    reconnect.backoff.max.ms = 1000
>     reconnect.backoff.ms = 50   request.timeout.ms = 120000     retries = 5
>     retry.backoff.ms = 100  sasl.jaas.config = null
>     sasl.kerberos.kinit.cmd = /usr/bin/kinit
>     sasl.kerberos.min.time.before.relogin = 60000
>     sasl.kerberos.service.name = null   sasl.kerberos.ticket.renew.jitter
>   = 0.05    sasl.kerberos.ticket.renew.window.factor = 0.8  sasl.mechanism = GSSAPI     security.protocol = PLAINTEXT   send.buffer.bytes = 131072  ssl.cipher.suites = null    ssl.enabled.protocols = [TLSv1.2, TLSv1.1,
>   TLSv1]    ssl.endpoint.identification.algorithm = null    ssl.key.password
>   = null    ssl.keymanager.algorithm = SunX509  ssl.keystore.location = null    ssl.keystore.password = null    ssl.keystore.type = JKS
>     ssl.protocol = TLS  ssl.provider = null
>     ssl.secure.random.implementation = null     ssl.trustmanager.algorithm =
>   PKIX  ssl.truststore.location = null  ssl.truststore.password = null
>     ssl.truststore.type = JKS
>
> 2018-04-17 17:19:00.553  INFO 59720 --- [           main]
>   o.a.kafka.common.utils.AppInfoParser     : Kafka version : 1.0.0
>   2018-04-17 17:19:00.553  INFO 59720 --- [           main]
>   o.a.kafka.common.utils.AppInfoParser     : Kafka commitId :
>   aaa7af6d4a11b29d

After which kafka starts listening to the topic but if i hit the endpoint written in my application its not working.
Even the console doesn't say me **Tomcat started on port XXXX**

Comment: Without code, this question will be difficult to answer. Please read [mcve].

Comment: hi Santanu, something similar here ... did you find a solution to your problem ?

Comment: Did you ever solve this? I Have an application using spring boot using configuration and discovery and it hangs on the "Kafka commit" message on start. Pretty much the same code works in a more simple app.